# codeigniter view display issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have created the CRUD operation and my view function doesn't display view page it shows the 404 error page.

My code is as following

`Controller`

```
public function view($slug = NULL)
    {
        $data['news_item'] = $this->news_model->get_news($slug);

        if (empty($data['news_item'])) {
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $data['news_item']['title'];

        $this->load->view('user/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('news/view', $data);
        $this->load->view('user/footer');
    }
```

`Model`

```
public function get_news($slug = FALSE)
    {
        if ($slug === FALSE)
        {
            $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')));
            return $query->result_array(); // $query->result(); // returns object
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('slug' => $slug, 'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('user_id')));
        return $query->row_array(); // $query->row(); // returns object


    }
```

`View`

```
<?php
echo '<h2>'.$news_item['title'].'</h2>';
echo $news_item['text'];
```

Comment: Did you configure the router for this?

Comment: So what ? you have `show_404()` function in your code, I suppose the function is called in your code. Debug your own code, we are not here for that.

Comment: no i have not ... my other functions are working fine like edit and delete

Comment: It's seems that the problem is from the controller class or the url that you call to access to it. what are those?

Comment: It would help if you could provide a valid path to your ressource. Like www.example.com/index.php/news/view/StoryOfMyLife, but without the domain.
Please create one and test it before your post it here, so you are sure it is not working.